# How to test the django profile pattern?

Tags: python, django

I don't get how to write a test for the extended user model in django.

Given the model for the [profile pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I tried the following tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from profiles.models import Profile

class ProfileTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Profile.objects.create(first_name='Robert',
                               last_name='Mayer',
                               email='rob@mayer.local',
                               password='123456',
                               department='bla')

    def test_profile_and_user_attributes(self):
        # exists for being a test stub
        pass
```

This will fail with:

```
TypeError: 'password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

or when commenting out password:

```
TypeError: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I know I could create my own User class based upon AbstractUser, where the tests above most probably would work out of the box. But given the OneToOneFiled solution: how to test that ?

Comment: Create a User object, create a Profile for that user and then try to create another Profile for that same user. It should fail because of the OneToOneField

Comment: My question is about testing the creation of an extended user model.

Comment: Yes but you cannot create an extended user model without creating a user

Comment: Another test would be to delete an extended user, and check if the corresponding user is also deleted (because of the models.CASCADE)

Comment: I want to test the extended user model which is already failing on setup.

Comment: I completely understand what you are trying to do. But because you are creating an extended user there will always be a regular django User instance as well. You can easily see this because there is a OneToOneField; that means there is a one-to-one relation to another object (in this case a User instance). You will always need to create a User instance first before you can create a Profile instance.